# How to specify external storage path?

Tags: android

How do I specify my own downloads folder path in my code?

path:

```
 static File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
static File ApkFileDirectory = new File(dir, "update.apk");
```

code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/"
                        + "update.apk")),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

I want to use `ApkFileDirectory` in my code.

I tried this but I am getting error "cannot resolve constructor"

```
`  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(new File(ApkFileDirectory),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);`
```

Comment: Try this: `public static final String ApkFileDirectory= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + "download";`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to SET the path to EXTERNAL storage. Here are the steps we used it has one downside and that is if you want to use INTERNAL storage with this design the name of the Database will be preceded with the word nullPassWord where PassWord is the name of your Database
First step is before the Database is created you create the path and send that String value to your DBHelper Class.

Use this code to define your String in any Activity

```
 public static String THE_PATH;
```

Then define that path in the same Activity like this

```
        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable);

        if(THE_PATH.contains("Android")){
            THE_PATH = THE_PATH + "/Documents/";
        }
```

Then in your DBHelper Class Import the reference to the String THE_PATH
and use that when the Database is created

```
 public static final String DB_NAME = THE_PATH + "PassWord";
```

The trick here is DO NOT create the Database until the String THE_PATH is populated